# RegexStringComparator BigTable Matching A Binary Number

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

In BigTable, when using the RegexStringComparator, is it possible to match a number in binary format. For example, suppose a Row Key has a number in it, but to save space and to have a predictable length, that number is stored as a 4 byte value rather than a separate character for each printable digit. Is it then possible to use the RegexStringComparator to match on the number?

Specifically, let's say I want to match on either of two integers `A` or `B`, then the regex might look like this...

`.*(A|B)`

To be more specific, let's say that A=284281344 which is 0x10f1ca00

`.*((\\x10\\xf1\x\xca\\x00 | B)`

I am finding that this does not seem to be possible due to higher valued bytes (perhaps non-ascii) such as `0xF1` which does not match.

Any recommendations or thoughts?

Comment: Still investigating, however I believe that the issue is unique to the emulator as the documentation states that "Regular expressions must contain only valid UTF-8 characters, unlike the actual Cloud Bigtable service which can process regular expressions as arbitrary bytes."

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the `\C` escape sequence (match a single byte even in UTF-8 mode)? Bigtable uses re2 regex flavor as described here:
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: Ya, I am aware of re2, and in fact that was my first thought, however whenever I try using the \C                                                                     
`Filter filter = new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new RegexStringComparator("\\C"));`,   I receive PatternSyntaxException